# define PI to 36 decimal place

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, pi, cmath

It is possible in C++ to do  this

```
ifndef M_PI
 define M_PI          3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
endif
```

In C# however, I've tried to declare a double var and assign it the value of PI with 36 decimals. 
This does not work because a double stores up to 16 decimals (MSDN docx). I tried creating an implicit type local variable but the compiler just declared it as a double and I  was back to square one. Maybe I can include `cmath` in C#?

How do I define PI to 36 decimal points in C#

Comment: For what purpose do you want the value of π at a precision higher than double precision?

Comment: Using decimal gets you a little closer: `decimal dec = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884M;`, looks like it'll give you 28 d.p. Past that you'll probably need a library for dealing with numbers which such high precision. But I'm also curious as to why you need that much precision.

Comment: Have you ever tried to print that value in C++? Whether it's a `double` or `long double`, you'll see the actual value you get is not what you have defined like that.

Comment: Here's an example to use a really big PI : https://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/calculating-pi-in-c-part-2-using-the-net-4-biginteger-class/

Comment: What makes you think it works in c++? The precision gets lost as soon as the literal gets translated into a variable.

Comment: I need the value of PI to the highest decimal possible to get my homography estimation as close to real as possible. @sharped thanks :) Im going to up the whole night tonight

Comment: Don't work the whole night ! Take a look at what I posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an article about calculating pi to 1 million digit in C#](http://latkin.org/blog/2012/03/20/how-to-calculate-1-million-digits-of-pi/), you can narrow it down to 36 digit

here is a sample code, I suggest reading the full article and the logic behind it.

```
public static HighPrecision GetPi(int digits)
{
    HighPrecision.Precision = digits;
    HighPrecision first = 4 * Atan(5);
    HighPrecision second = Atan(239);
    return 4 * (first - second);
}
```

if you just want to store pi (not calculating it) you can copy the value from [here](http://www.exploratorium.edu/pi/pi_archive/Pi10-6.html) and store it in `HighPrecision` variable.

Comment: He does not want to calculate PI, he wants to ***store*** PI. (but the post does provide a `HighPrecision` class that allows for arbitrary precision decimals)

Comment: so the problem is just narrowed down to BigDecimal like class in C#? @ScottChamberlain

Comment: `HighPrecision` class seems very interesting. I would love to know if @latkin have released his TPL version :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm using PI to calculate  the angle (theta) from the camera to the vertical  stand point of the camera.

Comment: @Tumelo - then you need about  2 or 3 digits.  3.14 will do.

Comment: @Tumelo and why do you need 36 digits of precesision to calculate theta? Also how do you plan on calculating theta, what data types does your function take?

Comment: @doctor  thanks a lot! The article was of big help although it took some time to understand the logic. I can get any number of decimals I want now

Answer (score 4):

What you can do in c++ and cannot do in C# is to create an alias for a literal. Writing in c++ `#define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884` doesn't define `PI` to 36 places. It just aliases the literal.

```
#define M_PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
double pi = M_PI;
```

It is exactly the same as writing

```
double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884;
```

Which would work pretty much identical in both c++ and C#. In c++ the value will have the same precision as in C#, because the literal will be interpreted into a `double` which I believe are essentially the same in both.

**The reason why `M_PI` is declared up to 36 digits is because this is maximal precision for `quad double`. Sadly there is no native type with such precision in C#.** In c++ you don't get anything special from `M_PI` unless you use it as `quad double`.

Having aliased literal doesn't help much it just allows to write:

```
    float pif = M_PI;
    int pii = M_PI;
    double pid = M_PI;
    quad double piq = M_PI;
```

Unfortunately you need to use custom types.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know C# has the highest precision in [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/364x0z75.aspx) `decimal` but it is only up to 28-29 significant decimal digits. I don't think you can cover up to 36 decimal digits in C# without using a custom library.

Comment: According to the doc, "Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.". I don't think Pi is included in financial/monetary calculations, so that datatype is probably not best suited for his needs.

Comment: @Sharped yes but you still need to implement your own scaling factor. I would still call it a "custom library", it is just one you yourself wrote. If you are going to do that, just go with a fully implemented one like [BigDecimal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigDecimal/) (gives you up to 64K of precision to the right of the decimal point) which has implemented the logic for the `+`, `-` and `*` operators too.

Comment: `bigint` or `long` is an integer type as the name denotes and does not have any decimal digit precision.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right, using it is another problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the question very interesting, so here are my 2 cents.

I take the Machin's formula [implementation](https://kashfarooq.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/calculating-pi-in-c-part-2-using-the-net-4-biginteger-class/), and applied it to the [IntXLib](https://github.com/devoyster/IntXLib) implementation of big integers (which have optimized multiply and divide operators with [Discrete Hartley transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Hartley_transform)).

Finally, I compared the result to the [Pi value posted here](http://www.exploratorium.edu/pi/pi_archive/Pi10-6.html).

Here, the 2500 decimals are computed in 138 ms on an i7 920 @2.66 Ghz.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String referencePi = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989380952572010654858632788659361533818279682303019520353018529689957736225994138912497217752834791315155748572424541506959508295331168617278558890750983817546374649393192550604009277016711390098488240128583616035637076601047101819429555961989467678374494482553797747268471040475346462080466842590694912933136770289891521047521620569660240580381501935112533824300355876402474964732639141992726042699227967823547816360093417216412199245863150302861829745557067498385054945885869269956909272107975093029553211653449872027559602364806654991198818347977535663698074265425278625518184175746728909777727938000816470600161452491921732172147723501414419735685481613611573525521334757418494684385233239073941433345477624168625189835694855620992192221842725502542568876717904946016534668049886272327917860857843838279679766814541009538837863609506800642251252051173929848960841284886269456042419652850222106611863067442786220391949450471237137869609563643719172874677646575739624138908658326459958133904780275900994657640789512694683983525957098258226205224894077267194782684826014769909026401363944374553050682034962524517493996514314298091906592509372216964615157098583874105978859597729754989301617539284681382686838689427741559918559252459539594310499725246808459872736446958486538367362226260991246080512438843904512441365497627807977156914359977001296160894416948685558484063534220722258284886481584560285060168427394522674676788952521385225499546667278239864565961163548862305774564980355936345681743241125";
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Restart();
    DecimalX calculatedPi = PiHelper.Calculate(2500);
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Pi with 2500 decimals in " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    String hmmmmm = calculatedPi.ToString();
    if (hmmmmm == referencePi)
        Console.WriteLine("Pi approximation found");
}

public class DecimalX
{
    /// Integer represatation of the decimal
    private readonly IntX _integerPart;
    /// Power of 10 (10^X)
    private readonly uint _scale;
    public DecimalX(IntX integerPart, uint scale)
    {
        _integerPart = integerPart;
        _scale = scale;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        IntX afterPoint = null;
        IntX beforePoint = IntX.DivideModulo(_integerPart, IntX.Pow(10, _scale, MultiplyMode.AutoFht), out afterPoint, DivideMode.AutoNewton);
        return beforePoint.ToString() + "." + afterPoint.ToString();
    }
}

public class PiHelper
{
    public static IntX InverseTan(int denominator, int numberOfDigitsRequired)
    {
        int demonimatorSquared = denominator * denominator;
        int degreeNeeded = GetDegreeOfPrecisionNeeded(demonimatorSquared, numberOfDigitsRequired);
        IntX tenToNumberPowerOfDigitsRequired = IntX.Pow(10, (uint)numberOfDigitsRequired, MultiplyMode.AutoFht);
        IntX s = IntX.Divide(tenToNumberPowerOfDigitsRequired, new IntX(2 * degreeNeeded + 1), DivideMode.AutoNewton); // s = (10^N)/c
        int c = 2 * degreeNeeded + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < degreeNeeded; i++)
        {
            c = c - 2;
            var temp1 = IntX.Divide(tenToNumberPowerOfDigitsRequired, new IntX(c), DivideMode.AutoNewton);
            var temp2 = IntX.Divide(s, new IntX(demonimatorSquared), DivideMode.AutoNewton);
            s = temp1 - temp2;
        }
        return IntX.Divide(s, new IntX(denominator), DivideMode.AutoNewton);
    }

    private static int GetDegreeOfPrecisionNeeded(int demonimatorSquared, int numberOfDigitsRequired)
    {
        int degreeNeeded = 0;
        while ((Math.Log(2 * degreeNeeded + 3) + (degreeNeeded + 1) * Math.Log10(demonimatorSquared)) <= numberOfDigitsRequired * Math.Log(10))
            degreeNeeded++;
        return degreeNeeded;
    }

    public static DecimalX Calculate(int numberOfDigitsRequired)
    {
        int max = numberOfDigitsRequired + 8; //  To be safe, compute 8 extra digits, to be dropped at end. The 8 is arbitrary
        var a = IntX.Multiply(InverseTan(5, max), new IntX(16), MultiplyMode.AutoFht); //16 x arctan(1/5)
        var b = IntX.Multiply(InverseTan(239, max), new IntX(4), MultiplyMode.AutoFht); //4 x arctan(1/239)
        return new DecimalX(IntX.Divide(a - b, IntX.Pow(10, (uint)8), DivideMode.AutoNewton), (uint)numberOfDigitsRequired);
    }
}
```

Now, you just have to implement all operators on the DecimalX type with "normal" types (like float / double / int / etc..), but I think it will be easy !

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** need that much precision, you can use arbitrary precision C libraries like [GNU MPC](http://www.multiprecision.org) or [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org). As they are C libraries so you'd need to use [interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to use them... But that'll restrict *usage* of your high precision `pi` to using the package you choose...